# Removing a folder name from a url using mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url structure that looks like this:

http://www.blahblah.com/community/i/pagename

However, I want to remove the ugly /i/ part. Is this possible with Modrewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)$ $1/i/$2 [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: That gives me an error. I don't know if it matters, but I already have one rule in my htaccess to remove my index.php. RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: I edited changing `(\w+)/(\w+)` into `^(\w+)/(\w+)$`, check now. If an error shows, post the error message it here.